# Getting data back from jinja to Flask?

Tags: html, forms, flask, jinja2

What I have right now is a list of ingredients displayed which looks like:

```
{% block content %}

<form method="POST">
    <h1>DATA</h1>
    {% for c in data %}
    <h1>{{ c.i_id }} {{ c.name }}</h1>
    {% endfor %}
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

What I'm having trouble with is displaying each item as a clickable, to have the user click on one and add it to a DB table "userIngredients" with values `u_id` and `i_id`. `u_id` is already stored on `session['u_id']`, however, `i_id` is what I'm trying to retrieve from the clickable items so I can complete the following query on each click: `'INSERT INTO userIngredients VALUES(%s,%s)',(session[u_id],i_id)`

```
@app.route('/addingredients', methods=['GET','POST'])
def addingredients():
    c = sq.connection.cursor()
    result = c.execute('SELECT * FROM Ingredients')
    data = c.fetchall()
    return render_template('user/addIngredients.html', data=data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use regular HTML for this.

```
<a href="/addingredients/{% session['u_id'] %}/{% c.i_id %}">{{ c.i_id }} {{ c.name }}</a>
```

Clicking this should trigger a response to your endpoint where you can use the following code to add it to the database

```py
@app.route('/addingredients/<user_id>/<ingredient_id>')
def add_ingredients(user_id, ingredient_id):
    # Important to cast the strings here to integers
    # both as protection from SQL injection and to make sure
    # the values are inserted as actual integers
    user_id = int(user_id)
    ingredient_id = int(ingredient_id)
    c = sq.connection.cursor()

    c.execute('INSERT INTO userIngredients VALUES(%s,%s)', (user_id,ingredient_id))

    # Then if you want, you can re-render the template
    result = c.execute('SELECT * FROM Ingredients')
    data = c.fetchall()
    return render_template('user/addIngredients.html', data=data)
```

I would move the rendering to a different endpoint than `/addingredients`, as the name doesn't really fit with the template. If you can, I'd suggest using either the RESTful `/ingredients/add` to add a new ingredient and `/ingredients` to get a list of all ingredients, or `/getingredients` and `/addingredients` to do the same thing